# How do I remove "Update and Shut Down" from the power options in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I've been scouring the internet the last few months in an attempt to block windows from doing automatic updates and generally running expensive processes in the background. It's just my preference.

I've Enabled the policy of "Do not Display Install Updates and Shut Down" option in my Group Policy editor. However, the options still remain.

I have also deleted all contents in `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\` and periodically clear them out manually. In the past this has worked, but the options remain.

I have set my power button (the physical one) options to just shut down, and I can use this to turn off my PC without updates. So, my PC has been turned on and off multiple times, so I don't believe there is any sort of "Refresh" solution that would cause the options to realize there is no pending update.

I know that recently windows has been more aggressive in denying me access to my own computer by way of restrictions on the registry editor and tamper-proof process that turn other processes back on. I've tried it every-which-way. Disabled actions via group policy editor, disabled services in the registry editor, disabled scheduled tasks that turn these back on automatically, but to no avail.

Is there any way to remove the "Update and Shut Down" options from the start menu? And additionally, is there any way for windows to stop checking for updates and reminding me about them?

Comment: Have you searched for similar questions? https://superuser.com/search?q=prevent+windows+update

Comment: If this is a work machine, ask Work. If this is your machine you cannot permanently stop updates so you might just as well do them. Set them to run overnight.

Comment: @spikey_richie I have indeed run the gamut of stack overflow answers